# Prove or disprove: if $f(n)\ge g(n)$ then $\log f(n) \ge \log g(n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, asymptotics

Prove or disprove:

> Let $f,g:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ be increasing functions, $0\notin \mathbb N$.
>
> If $f(n)\ge g(n)$ then $\log f(n) \ge \log g(n)$.

I think it's true because $\log$ function is also increasing.

Comment: That is the point; $\log$ is increasing. Also you don't need $f,g$ increasing

Comment: Whats up with the title?

Comment: @RedundantAunt sorry mix-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If with $ log $ you mean $ ln= log_e $ then the statement is true because $log_e$ it's increasing so, by definition of increasing function, you have the thesis. If you mean $ log_a $ and want to prove for every $a\in\Bbb R $ then it's false in general (just consider $a=\frac{1}{2}$ so that $log_\frac{1}{2}$ isn't increasing anymore)